# Is it possible to show a real Popover instead of default slide-out menu when using a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I am currently working with a UISplitViewController and instead of having this default slide-out-menu, i want a real UIPopover that appears if i click the UIBarButtonItem. What do i have to do and is there an easy way of configuring this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to overwrite the left bar button item, with the button that can be used to display the popover.
Use the following -

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Popover" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(presentPopover:)];

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Now you can use the target added, and then perform the associated function, as per your choice.

```
-(IBAction)presentPopover:(id)sender
{
// Perform your operations
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Then just use a popover view controller instead with the same content you would have used in the splitview pane that slides out.